# reference an xsd file in xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to xml language, I have one xml file and I created xsd schema for that file, but my problem is how to reference this schema in xml file. My xml schema look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wmh="http://www.wmhelp.com/2003/eGenerator"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://axis.com/service"
    xmlns="http://axis.com/service"
    version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="SWService" type="SWServiceType"/>
  <xs:element name="HWService" type="HWServiceType"/>


 <xs:complexType name="SWServiceType">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Service" type="ServiceType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="ServiceType">
 <xs:complexContent>
 <xs:extension base="IdType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="ServiceCustomers" type="ServiceCustomersType" maxOccurs="1" 
 minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="ServiceSuppliers" type="ServiceSuppliersType" maxOccurs="1" 
 minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="HWServiceType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="element" type="elementGroupType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ServiceCustomersType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="SoftWare" type="SoftWareType" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
  minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ServiceSuppliersType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="SoftWare" type="SoftWareType" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
 minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="HardWare" type="HardWareType" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
  minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="SoftWareType">
 <xs:complexContent>
 <xs:extension base="PathType">
  <xs:attribute name="Service" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="HardWareType">
 <xs:complexContent>
 <xs:extension base="PathType">
  <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Nr" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Service" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PathType">
  <xs:attribute name="Path" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>


   <xs:complexType name="elementGroupType">
 <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="element" type="elementType" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
 minOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>


 <xs:complexType name="elementType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="LM" type="LMType2" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="Service" type="ServiceType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Nr" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="LMType2">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="LowerMode" type="LowerModeType2" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
 minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="LowerModeType2">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="IdType">
    <xs:attribute name="Probability" type="xs:double" use="required"/>
  </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>


 <xs:complexType name="IdType">
  <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>

  </xs:schema>
```

I saved this file as as service.xsd.
I need to reference this schema in my xml file, i tried like this but it not validating.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service xsi:schemaLocation="file:///C:/main/newfolder/service.xsd"       
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://axis.com/service"        
 Version="1.0">
--------Xml data-------
 </Service>
```

I cant under what is the problem. It gives error like this

```
  No DTD of the document found
```

I tried like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service xsi:schemaLocation=""http://axis.com/service"       
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://axis.com/service"        
 Version="1.0">
--------Xml data-------
 </Service>
```

but still same problem.
when I validate xml file using xmlpad.
 Can any one fix my problem.any help appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1: One of the best first posts I've seen for a while!

Comment: Could you describe how you are validating the XML? Do you use some external program or maybe with some library?

Comment: @bbaja42 I am validating using XMLPAD.

Answer (score 1):

The use of schemaLocation is entirely optional and the Version attribute is incorrect in your instance (unless you have defined an attribute called Version in your schema)

The following instance

```
<Service xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://axis.com/service">
any string
</Service>
```

Validates fine against the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wmh="http://www.wmhelp.com/2003/eGenerator"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://axis.com/service"
    xmlns="http://axis.com/service"
    version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="Service" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

All I did was replace your type AxisServiceType with a string.

In order to determine the exact cause of the failure you are having I would need to see your entire schema and instance document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I am writing one xsd for different xml file formats, SWService,HWService,ModuleSpecification relates to different xml files and SWService xml file xsd is referenced under SWServiceType.like wise for three different xml files. I edited my post can have a look at my edited post. I need to reference this xsd in three different xml file formats. can you help me like that.If i reference this xsd without namespace its validating, but with name space it giving error.

Comment: I am sorry but you will have to provide me with the entire XSD schema in order that I can help you build an instance XML document.

Comment: Can you have a look at my xsd, I provided entire xsd schema.

Comment: Thanks - can you post your three different xml file formats? I can then help you see why these are not validating when you include the namespace from the schema. I will then update my original answer to include this.